# Branch points of $\log (\tan z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Does $\log (\tan z)$ have infinitely-many branch points on the real axis?

Near $z=\frac{n \pi}{2}$ (where $n$ is any integer), $\log (\tan z)$ appears to behave like $(-1)^{n} \log \left(z- \frac{n \pi}{2} \right). $

And if we wanted $\log(\tan z)$ to be well-defined on the complex plane, would an option be to cut out the entire real axis?

**EDIT**:

We can define $\log (\tan z)$ by integrating $2 \csc (2z)$ on the complex plane from $z= \frac{\pi}{4}$ (where $\log \left(\tan \frac{\pi}{4} \right) = 0$).

The function $2 \csc (2z)$ has simple poles at $n \pi$ with residue $1$ and simple poles at $\left(n+\frac{1}{2} \right) \pi $ with residue $-1$.

If we place branch cuts along the intervals $ \left[\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \pi , (n+1) \pi\right]$, the sum of the residues inside any closed loop will be zero.

So as Harald Hanche-Olsen explained in his answer below, $\log(\tan z)$ is indeed well-defined on the complex plane if these intervals are omitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were ridiculed for thinking that? That sounds … ridiculous.

Indeed, $\tan z$ has infinitely many simple zeroes and simple poles alternating along the real axis, and so each of these gives rise to a branch point. Cutting out the whole real axis seems desperate, though. Putting a branch cut between along the real axis at $[n\pi,(n+\frac12\pi)]$ for all $n$ should do the trick, since each zero and neighbouring pole cancel each other out, in a sense.

**Edited** to expand on that last bit: If you go once around a simple zero of a function in the positive direction, the argument of the function value increases by $2\pi$. Do the same around a pole, and it decreases by $2\pi$. Include one of each inside the contour, and the argument is unchanged. This is why connecting the two by a branch cut seems like such a good idea.

Comment: I had no time to go into further detail, so I considered posting as a comment instead. But then it seemed a bit long for a comment … Others might wish to provide for longer, more complete answers, though.

Comment: I was responding to someone's evaluation of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (\tan^{2}x)}{1+x^{2}} \ dx $ using contour integration.  My comment was that I didn't think one cut along the negative imaginary axis (including the origin) was sufficient.

Comment: Ah, but that *might* have been sufficient, if the contour was carefully chosen to contain an equal number of poles and zeroes of $\tan x$.